# How can I know what event is happening?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

In HTML5 I have 2 `<section>`s (2 boxes):

```
<section  id="leftbox">
  Drag an image here!
</section>

<section id="rightbox">
  <img id="pic" src="images/img1.jpg">
</section>
```

I want to move the image between the 2 boxes usingJS. I've the following:

```
leftbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
leftbox.addEventListener("dragleave", dragleave, false);
leftbox.addEventListener("dragover", function(e){e.preventDefault();}, false);
leftbox.addEventListener("drop", dropped , false);

rightbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
rightbox.addEventListener("dragleave", dragleave, false);
rightbox.addEventListener("dragover", function(e){e.preventDefault();}, false);
rightbox.addEventListener("drop", dropped , false);
```

For example, When I'm in function "dragleave", how can I know if the image came from the right or the left box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fully understand your Question,
But I guess you want to check if your dragged Item is from right or left box !!

Then you should do :

When `dragenter` then add the `data attribute` to the element that is dragged from the perticular box,by using something like `$(this).parent()` and define the `attribute` of dragged item if the box id is right then `right` or `left` for other ! And if you don't want to define the right or left then get `offsetLeft`.

May this helps you..
If you provide your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) then its easy to do so..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `parentNode` property of the element being dragged, for example

```
 var origin = document.getElementById(data).parentNode /* where data is the id
 of element being dragged.` which is set in the dataTransfer object of the event.*/
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/RcF2E/)